# Android NDK OpenCV linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: java, c++, opencv, android-ndk, android-studio-2.2

I'm building a android application with OpenCV. I use openCV in c++ and later call the c++ method from java using jni. when doing NDK build, it compile and build without an error, but when I'm going to run the application, it gives following error

`Error:error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

please help me cope, with anything..

Thankx

Comment: i am having the same problem did you get any solution to your question? help please!

Comment: have you configured javah and ndk external tools in project settings. and also make shure you have added correct parameters for them.